# Обращение из сервиса к сервиса(RESTful,Spring boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

*RESTful сервису 1* необходимо **получить данные** *с RESTful сервису 2*. Данные можно получить **по урлу: /products**.

Необходим пример реализации.

Comment: REST1 является обычным http-клиентом по отношению к REST2. Делаете запрос с помощью HttpURLConnection, полученный результат пропускаете через Gson или Jackson и обрабатываете результат.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, есть технологии для реализации общения между сервисами?

Comment: Вот как раз в моём первом комментарии описана технология общения между REST-сервисами. Можно ещё JAX-RS Client API использовать.